# NTLM Authentication from ConfiForms

Tags: api, authentication, exchangewebservices, ntlm, confluence

I am currently trying to use the EWS API directly from my ConfiForm. When I tested it with cURL, it only worked when I was using the NTLM authentication.

This is the cURL call I used:

`curl -v -u <user>:<password> -L https://example.com/ews/exchange.asmx -d "@ewstest.xml" -H "Content-Type:text/xml" --ntlm`

Now, I have a ConfiForm in Confluence, which when it a user sends it, I want to create a meeting in his exchange calendar.

But I can't seem to figure out how I do the NTLM authentication in a ConfiForm, or if it doesn't work that way, how should I do it instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem was with the issue that ConfiForms was not supporting NTLM2. It does now (introduced about 6 months ago).